# How to enable Breadcrumb for a non java file?

Tags: eclipse, spring-tool-suite, spring-tools-4

Working with `sts-4.5.1.RELEASE` (Based on `Eclipse`)

Having a non java file, is not possible enable Breadcrumb

[image]

For a Java file, is possible enable Breadcrumb

[image]

Is possible enable Breadcrumb for a non java file?

- Some special setting through `Preferences`?
- Some plugin available?

Consider a multi-module project with testing using `.properties` and `.sql` files, I think is valuable have Breadcrumb to know *at least* the location for these files

- `module-name` -> `main/test` -> `package/directory`

Through breadcrumb is possible see and select the package content to select and open an interface or class or other type

Furthermore an extra advantage for java files is that is possible select a method. Of course it is not possible for a non java file, but again is possible know the location and use the package content selection to choice other file sql, xml, .properties etc..

Comment: The breadcrumb is part of the Java editor, it isn't supported for anything else.

Comment: You can use the *Link with Editor* button (the double arrow on the top right corner of the *Package Explorer*) to quickly select the open file in the explorer. Arguably not as convenient as a breadcrumb, but still help to locate a file.

Comment: you should probably open a bug at Eclipse to file this as an enhancement request

Comment: @EmmanuelChebbi has sense, consider share your instructions through figures. I think is valuable...

Comment: @MartinLippert I thought that, but before - I needed a confirmation about is not possible neither through preferences nor a plugin. Thanks

Comment: @ManuelJordan I just posted a more visual answer

Comment: Reported - https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=560916

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:** I just discovered the [DevStyle plug-in](https://www.genuitec.com/products/devstyle/) that, among other things, provides a default breadcrumb in the toolbar:

[image: the DevStyle plugin provides breadcrumb even for non-Java files]

---

Breadcrumb is provided by the Java editor and thus not available for other files. As a workaround you can use the *Link with Editor* action [image: Link with Editor icon] that selects the open file in the explorer:

[image: demo of the Link with Editor action]

Arguably not as convenient as a breadcrumb but still help to locate a file.

---

**Note**: the action is a *toggle*, which means that once you've clicked on it the explorer will automatically update its selection whenever the active editor changes. You have to click on the *Link with Editor* action [image: Link with Editor icon] again to disable it.

Comment: Marked how a valid question by the moment until that feature is added (if is the case) - https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=560916

Comment: Even when "Link with Editor" would be used, through `Breadcrumb` is possible save window space. I am interested about that too ...

Comment: @ManuelJordan I just discovered the DevStyle plug-in which may provide a better solution; I updated my answer accordingly

Comment: Huge thanks for the update and interesting because some few hours ago I saw this through Twitter - https://twitter.com/brianfernandes/status/1244963637959118848 - seems that plugin is new ... I never heard about that